# c++ binarysearchtree insert

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm working on a project where I have to make a binary search tree that stores strings and takes account of doubles. While i've already tackled the specifics, I can't for the life of me get this damn insert function to work. It seems to only store the root node, leaving it's "children" NULL even though it does actually seem to assign the left and right pointers to new nodes. However when I attempt to output it, only the main parent (root) node exists. I guess the changes do not get saved for whatever reason.

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

typedef string ItemType; 

class Node
{
 public:
 Node(); // constructor 
 ItemType data; // contains item
 Node* left; // points to left child
 Node* right;// points to right child
 int dataCount; // keeps track of repeats
 vector<int> lineNumber; // keeps track of line numbers 
};

class Tree
{
 public:
 Tree(); // constructor
// ~Tree(); // destructor. not working.
 bool isEmpty(); // tests for empty tree
 Node* find(Node* root, ItemType item); // finds an item
 void insert(Node* root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree); // inserts an item
 void outputTree(Node* root); // lists all items in tree 
 void treeStats(Tree tree); // outputs tree stats 
 void clearTree(); // erases the tree (restart)
 Node* getRoot(); // returns the root
 void setRoot(Node*& root); 
// void getHeight(Tree *root); // gets height of tree

 private:
 Node* root; // root of tree
 int nodeCount; // number of nodes
};

#endif
```

cpp:

```
#include "BST.h"

bool setRootQ = true;

/** Node constructor- creates a node, sets children 
 *  to NULL and ups the count. */
Node::Node()
{
 left = right = NULL; 
 dataCount = 1;
}

/** Tree constructor- creates instance of tree
 *  and sets parameters to NULL */  
Tree::Tree()
{
 root = NULL; 
 nodeCount = 0; 
}

/** Destructor- deallocates tree/node data;
 *  avoids heap leaks. SOMETHING WRONG. CAUSES SEGFAULT
Tree::~Tree()
{
 if(this->root->left) // if a left child is present
 {
  delete this->root->left; //recursive call to destructor ("~Tree(->left)")
  this->root->left = NULL; 
 }
 if(this->root->right) // if a right child is present
 {
  delete this->root->right; //recursive call to destructor 
  this->root->right = NULL; 
 }
} */

/** Returns true if tree is empty. 
 *  Otherwise returns false (DUH). */
bool Tree::isEmpty()
{
 return root == NULL; 
}

/** Searches tree for item; returns the node if found
 * @param root- tree node.
 *   item- data to look for. */
Node* Tree::find(Node* root, ItemType item)
{
 if(root == NULL) // if empty node
 {
  return NULL;
 }
 else if(item == root->data) // if found
 {
  return root; 
 }
 else if(item < root->data) // if item is less than node 
 {
  find(root->left, item); 
 }
 else if(item > root->data) // if item is more than node
 {
  find(root->right, item); 
 }

 return NULL;
}

/** Adds a new node to the tree. If duplicate, increases count. 
 * @param item- data to insert.
 *   root- tree node/ */
void Tree::insert(Node* root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree)
{
 Node* temp = find(tree.getRoot(), item);
 if(temp != NULL) // if item already exists
 {
  temp->dataCount += 1;
  temp->lineNumber.push_back(lineN);
  return;
 }

 if(root == NULL) // if there is an empty space
 {
  root = new Node;   // insert new node  
  root->data = item; // w/ data value
  root->lineNumber.push_back(lineN);
  nodeCount++; 

  if(setRootQ)
  { 
   setRoot(root);
   setRootQ = false;
  } 
  return; 
 }

 if(item < root->data)
 {
  insert(root->left, item, lineN, tree);
 }
 if(item > root->data)
 {
  insert(root->right, item, lineN, tree);
 }
}

/** Outputs tree to console in inorder.
 * @param root- tree root. */
void Tree::outputTree(Node* root)
{
 if(isEmpty()) // if empty tree
 {
  cout << "Error: No items in tree" << endl; // error message
 }
 else
 { 
  if(root->left != NULL)
  {
   outputTree(root->left);
  }

  cout << "- " << root->data << " (" << root->dataCount << ") line#s: ";
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < root->lineNumber.size(); i++)
  {
   cout << root->lineNumber[i] << ", ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  if(root->right != NULL)
  {
   outputTree(root->right);
  }
 }
}

/** Displays tree stats including number of nodes,
 *  tree height, and more frequent item.
 * @param tree- tree instance. */
void Tree::treeStats(Tree tree) 
{
 cout << "Number of entries: " << nodeCount << endl;
 // unfinished
}

/** Clears tree. 
void Tree::clearTree()
{
 this->~Tree();
} */

/** Returns the root of the tree. */
Node* Tree::getRoot()
{
 return root;
}

void Tree::setRoot(Node*& rootS)
{
 root = rootS;
}
```

I realize my destructor isn't working but I'll tackle that myself later. I've been pulling my hair out over this trying to figure out what I'm missing, but to no avail. If anyone can give me any help and point me in the direction towards a solution I would greatly appreciate it.

i think it *might* have something to do with

```
void Tree::insert(Node* root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree)
```

and instead should be something like

```
void Tree::insert(Node* &root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree)
```

but when i try i get a "no matching function" error. :/

Comment: Sorry - why are you not using std::map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you suggest yourself (with `insert()` taking `Node *&` root) will work. You have to make a corresponding change to the .h file, AND also change `getRoot()` to return `Node *&` in both .h and .cc files.

This will work. But your code has other problems. For example, `setRoot` and `setRootQ` don't do anything useful, as far as I can tell. The fourth argument to `insert()` only confuses things and does nothing to detect duplicates. It should be removed. To detect a duplicate simply do `if (item == root->data)` just before you do `if (item < root->data)` in the `insert()` method (i.e. it'll be even more similar to `find()`).

Also, if anyone besides you will ever use your code, you shouldn't require passing in `getRoot()` to methods like `find()` and `insert()`. Instead, create private helper methods, like `find_helper(Node*, Item)` and `insert_helper(Node*&,Item)`, and have the public methods call them with the root node as the first argument. E.g.:

```
Node *find(Item item) { return find_helper(root, item); }
```

This would also make the weird return type of `getRoot()` unnecessary, and you could change it back to returning the plain `Node*`, or get rid of that accessor altogether.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!! having that find() in my insert was annoying the heck out of me. I don't know why I overlooked such an easy solution lol. Brain fart. Anyway, my insert is working fine now. Thanks again. :D

Comment: Oh and about the private helper methods. Good advice. Yes, this particular code is just for me but I think it would be good practice to get in the habit of doing so. THANK YOU, man, I was beating myself over this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a lot of pointer comparison occurring but the pointer member variables are not being initialized. Ensure that the pointer member variables are initialized properly so that they evaluate properly in if statements.

Change from:

```
class Node
{
 public:
 Node(); // constructor 
...  
};  

to   

class Node
{
 public:
 Node() : left(0), right(0) {}
...
};
```

Comment: thanks, tried it, but didn't work. wouldn't that be the same as       Node::Node(){ left = right = NULL;} as i have it? please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @FAllen - My apologies, I missed that line of code when I reviewed the code.

Comment: Another thought regarding the signature: void Tree::insert(Node* root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree).  The root argument is declared as a value as opposed to a reference.  Try changing it to: void Tree::insert(Node** root, ItemType item, int lineN, Tree tree) and pass in the address of the pointer.